# Как расположить элемент во весь экран с заданным отношением сторон?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Я делаю canvas-игру. Нужно расположить canvas так, чтобы он сохранял пропорции при изменении размера окна и чтобы всегда касался верхней и нижней или правой и левой сторон окна.

На рисунке: чёрным - окно, красным - canvas. Везде одинаковые пропорции.

Спасибо за помощь!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, 
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }

.wrapper, 
.wrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }

.wrapper { width: 100vw; height: 0; padding-bottom: 60%; }

  .wrapper > canvas {
    width: calc(100vh * (1 / 0.6)); height: 100%; 
    max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #f00; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Похоже что в сниппете отображается некорректно, [вот то же самое в codepen](https://codepen.io/yar85/pen/VwYMNgQ).